# Using two Frames in a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm developing a GUI that is kinda like a menu to control an assembly line. When the program runs, it shows up the window with the first set of buttons. Clicking in a button should make this window disappear and should make another window appear with the previously chosen menu. How do I implement the action on the button? Both menus are in different classes and there's an extra class with the main function that, for now, only creates new objects and set the visibility of the first window to true.

Here are both of them:

Main one:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class InfInd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The first Menu:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Cliente extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public JLabel titulo;
    public JButton ordens;
    public JButton listaordens;
    public JButton stats;
    public JButton desc;
    public JButton sair;

    public Cliente() {
        titulo = new JLabel("Menu Cliente");
        ordens = new JButton ("Ordens");
        listaordens = new JButton("Lista Ordens");
        stats = new JButton ("Estatísticas");
        desc = new JButton ("Peças Descarregadas");
        sair = new JButton ("Sair");

        setLayout(null);

        Dimension size1 = titulo.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size2 = ordens.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size3 = listaordens.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size4 = stats.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size5 = desc.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size6 = sair.getPreferredSize();

        titulo.setBounds(100, 50, size1.width, size1.height);
        ordens.setBounds(100, 100, size2.width, size2.height);
        listaordens.setBounds(100, 150, size3.width, size3.height);
        stats.setBounds(100, 200, size4.width, size4.height);
        desc.setBounds(100, 250, size5.width, size5.height);
        sair.setBounds(100, 300, size6.width, size6.height);

        sair.addActionListener(this);

        add(titulo);
        add(ordens);
        add(listaordens);
        add(stats);
        add(desc);
        add(sair);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setTitle("Teste");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent out){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The second menu is similar to this one, only with different names for the buttons. The idea is to, for now, just show up the second menu by clicking on the "Ordens" button. Sorry of this seems quite noobish but I've only started with Java GUIs yesterday. Thank you all.

Comment: You should rethink your design.  In general, you only want one JFrame per application.  There are better ways to switch between screens in java.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private JButton jbt = new JButton("Open Window");
    private AnotherFrame jfrm = new AnotherFrame();    // another frame

    public MyFrame(){
        add(jbt);
        add(jfrm);  // add frame

        jbt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                jfrm.setVisibility(true);      // when button clicked, set
            }                                  // visibility for other frame true
        });
    }

    private AnotherFrame extends JFrame {
        public AnotherFrame(){
        }
    }
}
```